# ES2017 with NativeScript 7

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, nativescript

I am using NativeScript 7 with Plain JavaScript and I am trying to write the View Model code in ES2017.
By ES2017, I mean I am using features that are released at or before ES2017, such as `import/export` and `class` syntax.

The code runs successfully but the data is not bound. Here is the code.

**View Model**

```
import { fromObject } from "@nativescript/core";

export class MainViewModel extends fromObject {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.counter = 69;
        this.message = "meow";
    }
    

    getMessage(counter) {
        if (counter <= 0)
            return "Hoorraaay! You unlocked the NativeScript clicker achievement!";
        else
            return `${counter} taps left`;
    }

    onTap() {
        console.log("Tapped");
        this.message = this.getMessage(this.counter);
        this.counter--;
        console.log(this.counter);
    }
}
```

**Main Page**

```
import { MainViewModel } from "./main-view-model";

exports.onNavigatingTo = function(args) {
    console.log("OnNavigatingTo is called");
    const page = args.object;
    page.bindingContext = new MainViewModel();
};
```

**Main Page XML**

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" navigatingTo="onNavigatingTo">
    <ActionBar title="My App" icon=""></ActionBar>
    <StackLayout class="p-20">
        <Label text="Tap the button" class="h1 text-center"/>
        <Button text="TAP" tap="{{ onTap }}" class="-primary"/>
        <Label text="{{ message }}" class="h2 text-center" textWrap="true"/>
    </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

Given that NativeScript 7 runs ES2017, why isn't this code working (data being bound)?
What am I missing?

Also, please note that `console.log` shows nothing so far.

**EDIT**

To clarify what I meant by "data being bound", I mean that neither the "message" attribute nor the "onTap()" function are bound to the view as expected.
[image: Data not bound to view NS7 ES2017.]

**ONE MORE EDIT - WORKING ES5 CODE**

**ViewModel**

```
const fromObject = require("@nativescript/core").fromObject;

exports.MainViewModel =  fromObject({
    counter: 69,
    message: "meow",
    
    getMessage: function(counter) {
        if (counter <= 0)
            return "Hoorraaay! You unlocked the NativeScript clicker achievement!";
        else
            return `${counter} taps left`;
    },

    onTap: function() {
        console.log("Tapped");
        this.message = this.getMessage(this.counter);
        this.counter--;
        console.log(this.counter);
    }
});
```

**Main Page**

```
const MainViewModel = require("./main-view-model").MainViewModel;

exports.onNavigatingTo = function(args) {
    console.log("OnNavigatingTo is called");
    const page = args.object;
    page.bindingContext = MainViewModel;
};
```

**Main Page XML (Same)**

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" navigatingTo="onNavigatingTo">
    <ActionBar title="My App" icon=""></ActionBar>
    <StackLayout class="p-20">
        <Label text="Tap the button" class="h1 text-center"/>
        <Button text="TAP" tap="{{ onTap }}" class="-primary"/>
        <Label text="{{ message }}" class="h2 text-center" textWrap="true"/>
    </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

**Screenshot of working ES5 code**

[image: Working ES5 code]

Comment: `import`/`export` and `class` syntax is ES6 aka ES2015.

Comment: Exactly. Given that the V8 engine powering NativeScript 7 runs ES2017 (which is obviously after ES2015), the previous code should work, shouldn't it?

Comment: What do you mean by "data being bound"? What exactly is the error?

Comment: @Bergi Please see my edits to the question.

Comment: Ok, so this seems to be a nativescript problem. Or is it specifically a ES6 problem, i.e. could you get an ES5 version of the code to work?

Comment: Yes, the default ES5 version of the code works. Would Babel work with this? Do you have an idea how to set it up? Btw, what is frustrating is that it is marketed to run ES2017 by default and hence my question.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to add the working ES5 code, please? Also, did you try converting your existing code to ES6+ or were you following some tutorial that demonstrated the new features?

Comment: Edited. I did not follow any tutorial as I couldn't find one, so I decided to make one. As written in this [article](https://nativescript.org/blog/nativescript-7-announcement/), they are targeting es2017. This made me want to test it out.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I figured it out. My mistake was inheriting fromObject, which is a method that returns an object of type **Observable**. Instead, I imported Observable and inherited from it and the code worked like a charm.

Note, though, that in the main-page file, `import` syntax did not work, so I had to use to `require` instead. Here is my code.

**Main View Model**

```
import { Observable } from "@nativescript/core";

export class MainViewModel extends Observable {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.counter = 69;
        this.message = "meow";
    }

    getMessage() {
        if (this.counter <= 0)
            return "Hoorraaay! You unlocked the NativeScript clicker achievement!";
        else
            return `${this.counter} taps left`;
    }

    onTap() {
        console.log("Tapped");
        this.set("message", this.getMessage());
        this.set("counter", this.counter-1);
        console.log(`message = ${this.message}. counter = ${this.counter}`);
    }
}
```

**Main Page**

```
const MainViewModel = require("./main-view-model").MainViewModel;

exports.onNavigatedTo = function(args) {
    console.log("OnNavigatedTo is called");
    const page = args.object;
    page.bindingContext = new MainViewModel();
};
```

**Main Page XML**

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" navigatedTo="onNavigatedTo">
    <ActionBar title="My App" icon=""></ActionBar>
    <StackLayout class="p-20">
        <Label text="Tap the button" class="h1 text-center"/>
        <Button text="TAP" tap="{{ onTap }}" class="-primary"/>
        <Label text="{{ message  }}" class="h2 text-center" textWrap="true"/>
    </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

Note that calling the `set` method in the View Model is a must for changing the bound data in the UI.

[image: ES2017 Code working in NativeScript 7]

This makes coding in NativeScript Core 7 a whole lot cleaner.